# How to use Aspectc++ with C++v11?

Tags: c++11, aop

I want to use the aspectc++ compiler for a C++11-project. I have read in the manual, that c++11 support will come with version 2. I thought that aspect weaving happens only on the code level, so why does it depend on the used C++ version? Why does aspectc++ care the source code when it just has to weave the aspects to generate a composed piece of code? Is there a way to use aspectc++ for C++11 source code? Or is there an alternative which can handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is already a bit older, i know.
Nevertheless I'd like to answer the question why aspectC++ depends on the C++-version:

aspectC++ internally parses the code (amongst other things to identify the locations where to weave the code). Not all of this can be done by external parsers therefore it needs to understand the syntax basically itself.
Some new c++-constructions from C++11 like attributes ([[...]]) could not be handeled by the AspectC++-compiler version < 2.0.

To use c++11 for compiling just use -std=c++11